# C++ using auto vs a defined iterator

Tags: c++, c++11, iterator, auto

Could anyone explain the differences in the for loops in my code? I understand that an iterator is a pointer to some data, and when I type "*iter" I'm accessing the value that this pointer points to (an int). But I don't understand why auto doesn't work the same way here. Why don't I need to dereference vertex in the other for loop?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <queue>

class Graph {
    public:
        Graph(int num_v): num_vertices(num_v), adj_list(new std::list<int>[num_v]) {}

        void add_edge(int u, int v) { adj_list[u].push_back(v); }

        void bfs_traversal(int start) {
            bool* visited = new bool[num_vertices];
            for (int i = 0; i < num_vertices; i++)
                visited[i] = false;
            std::queue<int> q;
            visited[start] = true;
            q.push(start);
            //std::list<int>::iterator iter;
            while(! q.empty()) {
                int node = q.front();
                std::cout << node << " ";
                q.pop();

                /*
                for (iter = adj_list[node].begin(); iter != adj_list[node].end(); ++iter) {
                    if (! visited[*iter]) {
                        visited[*iter] = true;
                        q.push(*iter);
                    }
                */

                for (auto vertex : adj_list[node]) {
                    if (! visited[vertex]) {
                        visited[vertex] = true;
                        q.push(vertex);
                    }
                }

            }
        }

    private:
        int num_vertices;
        std::list<int>* adj_list;
};

int main() 
{
    Graph graph(4);
    graph.add_edge(0,1);
    graph.add_edge(0,2);
    graph.add_edge(1,2);
    graph.add_edge(2,0);
    graph.add_edge(2,3);
    graph.add_edge(3,3);

    std::cout << "breadth first traversal starting from vertex 2\n";

    graph.bfs_traversal(2);

    return 0;
}
```

compile with: g++ -std=c++11 
source: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/breadth-first-traversal-for-a-graph/

Comment: Range based for loop.

Comment: @tobi303: No, it's correct. The container contains `int`s, and doing `*iter` will give them an `int`.

Comment: @You well I just got confused, because it is written in a way that can be mistunderstood

Answer (score 6):

The uncommented version is using the *range-based* `for` loop.

Note that there is a subtle difference; unlike the iterator version, `vertex` is a value copy of the container element. It's for this reason that

```
for (const auto& vertex : adj_list[node]) {
```

is preferred when working with larger containee types, or even `auto&& vertex`.

Under the hood, the range based notation uses iterators. It's important to remember therefore that the C++03 rules for iterator invalidation still apply.

Answer (score 5):

Because the [range-based for-loop](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) does it for you. In this specific case (assuming [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11)), it's required to produce code equivalent to the following (variable names are *for exposition only*):

```
{
  auto && __range = adj_list[node]; 
  for (auto __begin = __range.begin(), __end = __range.end(); 
       __begin != __end; ++__begin) { 
    auto vertex = *__begin; 
    // ... 
  } 
}
```

Note line 5, where a copy is made after dereferencing the iterator.

---

As @Bathsheba points out, it's likely that you want `const auto&` instead of just `auto`.

Comment: I believe it's a *requirement* not an *essence*. Although the standards committee keeps dicking about with the requirement.

Comment: I was intentionally fudging the wording here because the precise equivalent code depends on the type of the container, and on the exact standard used for compilation (and the variable names are "for exposition only", so there's that). I'll update the wording a bit, though.